# Hibernate + MySQL Process remaining in "sleep" state

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I know there has been a lot of questions on this topic, but I found no answer that suits my needs. 
I have a very simple requirement: open a connection to a MySQL database, make a query, get the result and close the connection.

Here is my code:

**Hibernate file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.254.90:3306/db</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">0</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Java class:**

```
final URL resourceUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("blabla.xml");
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(new File(resourceUrl.toURI()));
final SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);
final String sqlQueryStr = "SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = 'blabla'";
final Query sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQueryStr);
session.beginTransaction();
final Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE).uniqueResult()
final String resultStr = result.get("col1").toString();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

This code leaves me with 1 process in MySQL that remains in "sleep" state, why? Moreover, if I want to reuse this session, it does not work because I did close it. So why does it let a "sleep" process, and in the same time cannot use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the remaining process is the tool you use to check for sleeping process

Comment: @RC, no, I'm aware of that ;)